# RavenDB 4.0 storing raw json

Tags: c#, json, json.net, ravendb, ravendb4

I'm using NLOG for logging with the JsonLayout and want to store these logs in RavenDB 4.0. **Basically I'm trying to store raw json into ravendb using the RavenDB .NET client.**

I had a working solution in RavenDB 3.5: using a class inheriting from "RavenJObject" but this functionality was depricated in 4.0.

I got it working by deserializing the json into a dynamic and storing the dynamic object. But this stores the document in a meaningless "JObjects" collection. It also seems overhead to convert json to dynamic and back to json again.

```
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);
        session.Store(obj);
```

I know it's possible using the UI (raven studio). But i can't find a way doing it using the .Net client.

I think it's maybe possible using the http api, doing a post with the raw json. But I haven't found any documentation about this.

Who can help me out? Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you have code sample which allows you to operate on generic type and assigns collection properly:

```
[Fact]
public void RawJson()
{
    using (var store = GetDocumentStore())
    {
        using (var session = store.OpenSession())
        {
            var json = "{ 'Name' : 'John', '@metadata' : { '@collection': 'Users' } }";
            var blittableJson = ParseJson(session.Advanced.Context, json);

            var command = new PutDocumentCommand("users/1", null, blittableJson);
            session.Advanced.RequestExecutor.Execute(command, session.Advanced.Context);
        }

        using (var session = store.OpenSession())
        {
            var user = session.Load<User>("users/1");
            Assert.Equal("John", user.Name);
        }
    }
}

public BlittableJsonReaderObject ParseJson(JsonOperationContext context, string json)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
    {
        return context.ReadForMemory(stream, "json");
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```